# Problem with csquotes, greek and bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, babel, greek, csquotes, ucharclasses

I cannot seem to be able to use quotation marks correctly. I have loaded *csquotes* package, and I am also using *ucharclasses* to automatically change hyphenation rules in my text. Below you can see the MWE and the result:

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}

%%%Font and Languages%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes}                                          % Suggested Prerequisite for babel package
\setromanfont{Kerkis}
\usepackage[Latin,Greek]{ucharclasses}                      % This Package allows the setTransitionTo commands, which are necessary for bilingual text
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\setTransitionTo{BasicLatin}{\hyphenrules{english}}     % Try to change hyphenation only, lighter
\setTransitionTo{GreekAndCoptic}{\hyphenrules{greek}}   % Change language depending on character read

%%%%Bibliography%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}   
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}                                             %For Uline command below
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black}   %Make URLS blue
% %% Underline in line URLS hyperef
\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \catcode`\$=6 %
  \catcode`\#=12 %
  \gdef\href@split$1#$2#$3\\$4{%
    \hyper@@link{$1}{$2}{\uline{$4}}% or \underline
    \endgroup
  }%
\endgroup
 
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Ελληνικά}
\selectlanguage{greek}
"Ελληνικά"
 
 "English"\cite{libreThermo}
 
 \selectlanguage{english}
"Ελληνικά" \cite{feynman1992there}
 
 "English" \cite{dawon1963electric}
 
 \printbibliography[title={Βιβλιογραφία}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that when in text, no matter what language I select, the English quotation marks appear. On the other hand, in the bibliography, no matter the language, I get Greek style quotation marks.

Comment: you must load csquotes with the autostyle option `\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}`, and you must also use (the bibliography does it), e.g. with `\enquote{English}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the reply. My only problem now is that bibliography uses the quotation marks of the last selected language of the text, no matter the entry's language. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: well you didn't show your bib so I couldn't test that. Try the `language=autobib` for biblatex and check the biblatex docu.